# IE10 Compatibility Mode

Tags: internet-explorer, compatibility, internet-explorer-10

When a user who is using Internet Explorer 10 clicks on the "compatibility" button, what rendering engine does IE10 use? Does it default to IE7's Standards Mode? Or does it use a different older versions's rendering mode?

Comment: Yes, it defaults to IE7 in standards mode.

Comment: Sorry for duplicating the question. For some reason I could not find the question that you linked to in the search. Probably didn't search the correct terms (mis-spelling). Thanks again for the concise answer and link (for expanded explanation).